# Fit multiple linear regression without an intercept with the function lm() in R

Tags: r, statistics

can you please help with this question in R, i need to get more than one predictor:
Fit multiple linear regression without an intercept with the function lm() to train data
using variable (y.train) as a goal variable and variables (X.mat.train) as
predictors. Look at the vector of estimated coefficients of the model and compare it with
the vector of ’true’ values beta.vec graphically
(Tip: build a plot for the differences of the absolute values of estimated and true values).

i have already tried it out with a code i will post at the end but it give me only one predictor but in this example i need to get more than one predictor:
and i think the wrong one is the first line but i couldn't find a way to fix it :

i can't put the data set here it's large but i have a variable that stores 190 observation from a victor (y.train) and another value that stores 190 observation from a matrix (X.mat.trian)..  should give more than one predictor but for me it's giving one..

```
simple.fit = lm(y.train~0+ X.mat.train) #goal var #intercept # predictor
summary(simple.fit)# Showing the linear regression output
plot(simple.fit)
abline(simple.fit)

n <- summary(simple.fit)$coefficients
estimated_coeff <- n[ , 1]
estimated_coeff
plot(estimated_coeff)
#Coefficients: X.mat.train   0.5018   
v <- sum(beta.vec)
#0.5369
plot(beta.vec)
plot(beta.vec, simple.fit)
```

Comment: Your code seems to be fine - I'm getting 3 regression coefficients and no intercept when I run it with `y.train <- runif(10)` and `X.mat.train <- cbind(a=runif(10), b=runif(10), c=runif(10))`. This may be particular to your data set - please consider making your example reproducible by providing the actual values with something like `dput`.

Comment: @Dubukay i can't put the data set here it's large but i have a variable that stores 190 observation from a victor (y.train) and another value that stores 190 observation from a matrix (X.mat.trian)..  should give more than one predictor but for me it's giving one..

Comment: Try posting `dput(head(X.mat.train, 20))` and `dput(head(y.train, 20))` to just share the first 20 values

Comment: it didn't work i tried